# How can I set the baud rate automatically when a device connects?

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, usb, stty

I can use `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 19200` to set the baud rate whenever I want. But I'd like to set it automatically when a device is plugged in. Is there some sort of configuration file I can put this in?

I'm doing this on a [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) for this.

Write a udev rule in directory */etc/udev/rules.d* for your device that executes the shell script you want.

See *[udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev)* (Arch Linux) for writing *udev* rules. You can use i.e. USB *vendorID* and *productID* to identify the device. For that, you write the script

`KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12ba", ATTRS{idProduct}=="58ea", ATTRS{model}=="XYZ42", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/pathto/script"`

*[How can I run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in)*

Answer (score 2):

Create a udev rule file, e.g., `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ttyUSB.rules` and put the following line there:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="YYYY", RUN+="/bin/stty -F /dev/%k 19200"
```

Replace XXXX and YYYY with your vendor/product id values respectively. You can obtain those by running `lsusb`